# How Much Ammonium Chloride for Home-made Salt Licorice?

Tags: salt, candy

I want to make my own Scandinavian style salt licorice. I was able to buy ammonium chloride at a local spice store, but I am not sure how much to use. My research, so far, has suggested a concentration of anywhere from 2 to 8%. (It seems 7.99% is the legal limit in Germany for human consumption.) First, I am assuming that this is a percentage of total weight, correct? Second, is there a particular point in the cooking process when the ammonium chloride should be added? Is there a particular technique that should be utilized, e.g. make a slurry?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm looking forward to what people have to say here.

Comment: Are we sure the "candy" tag is appropriate here? :)

Comment: I don't see why not. It's asking specifically about a candy-making process. If the question were about baking, the answer would be very different and would belong in a different category.

Answer (score 1):

The percent of ammonium chloride listed is in regards to the total weight of the ingredients used. After making a few batches, I have found that adding the ammonium chloride along with the sugar offers great results. Finally, here is an equation to figure out how much ammonium chloride to use, given you know what percentage you want to have:

K = Known Weight of Ingredients (Everything in the recipe except for Ammonium Chloride)

X = Weight of Ammonium Chloride

Z = X's % of Total Weight of Ingredients expressed as a decimal (e.g. 0.06 for 6%)

T = Total Weight of Ingredients

Step 1: T = K / (1-Z)

Step 2: T - K = X

Step 3: Make some salmiak licorice.